# tag based image to display in UIButton using objective-c

Tags: ios

I am developing an app for kids game.
I am new to this field.
I have store 5 images in an NSMutableArray.Images are:

```
Printing description of self->dict:
<__NSArrayM 0x6080000458e0>(
<UIImage: 0x60800009ef50>, {300, 300},
<UIImage: 0x60800009eaf0>, {640, 480},
<UIImage: 0x60800009ec30>, {640, 480},
<UIImage: 0x60800009ee10>, {1024, 768},
<UIImage: 0x60800009e140>, {1920, 1200}
```

I have 10 UIImageView in UIView.I need to set  this  images in the UIButton.Based on tag.randomly generating tag.how to do

Comment: give more info.

Comment: Use `rand()` function to get random number between 0 to 4 and then use this number to get index of array. This makes some what random image order.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just create the class for holding your **image** and **tag**.
Add that instance object in Array, Every Array element contains 2 things tag and image